# A modification to %esp cause SIGSEGV

Tags: linux, assembly, g++, 64-bit, x86-64

Sometimes I use the following code to avoid stack overflow when taking part in coding competition.

```
int main()
{
  static const int _STACK_SIZE = MAXN*10;
  static int _STACK[_STACK_SIZE*2], _ESP;
  __asm__ __volatile__
  (
      "movl %%esp, %0\n" 
      "movl %1, %%esp\n":
      "=g"(_ESP):
      "g"(_STACK + _STACK_SIZE):
  );


  // Do Something..


  __asm__ __volatile__
  (  
      "movl %0, %%esp\n":
      :
      "g"(_ESP):
  );
}
```

As far as I know, this asm code backups `%esp` and moves the stack to `_STACK[]`.

---

**My Question: Why this code cause `SIGSEGV` on a x86-64 Linux Server(It runs well on my own x86 Linux)? And how to fix it?**

I guess, maybe it's because `%esp` is a 64-bit pointer??

I tried to delete the `__asm__ __volatile__("movl %0, %%esp\n": : "g"(_ESP):);` and it seems runs well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because in x86-64 assembly modifying a 32-bit register such as `esp` zeroes the highest 32 bits of the corresponding 64-bit register, `rsp` in this case. In x86-64 the stack pointer `rsp` is a 64-bit register.

x86-64 Linux always puts the stack pointer near the top of the user-space range of virtual address space, like `0x7fffffffe6d0` for example, so it's always outside the low 32 bits of virtual address space. The high half of RSP is non-zero and ESP != RSP.

So by modifying `esp` you make `rsp` point to an address where your program has no access rights, and thus cause a segmentation fault. In x86-64 code you don't normally use `esp` at all, and you should replace all instances of `esp` with `rsp` in your x86-64 code.

Comment: Thanks! Got it! So, Change `esp` to `rsp` && `int` to `long` ?

Comment: "The problem should occur only in computers that have less that 4 GiB of total memory"  You mean "_more than_ 4 GiB"..?

Comment: Standard myth about demand-paged virtual memory operating systems.  You are mixing up "total memory" with the size of the virtual memory address space.  The latter is *much* greater, the amount of RAM on the machine is irrelevant.

Comment: @Michael Obviously, thanks. "more" and "less" and so difficult concepts ;)

Comment: @HansPassant I meant virtual memory address space (including swap), but didn't catch up the right word. Thanks, corrected as I meant it. Feel free to correct it if my wording is still inadequate.

Comment: @abcdabcd987 In Linux `long` should be the correct type, you may want to check also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384502/what-is-the-bit-size-of-long-on-64-bit-windows

Comment: @abcdabcd987 - changing to `rsp` is still inadequate. The x86-64 ELF ABI specifies a 16-byte aligned stack. Furthermore, gcc isn't aware of the changes to stack, so any use of `rbp` (the frame pointer) may fail.