# ESP register dereference segmentation fault, x86

Tags: macos, assembly, stack, x86-64, cpu-registers

I am trying to follow along this [tutorial](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/04/where-the-top-of-the-stack-is-on-x86/) on the stack in x86 assembly. It seemed to me that `esp` is a register containing a pointer to the top of the stack - and to test this out I dereferenced `esp` and tried to store its value in `eax`. This gave me a segmentation fault, and I cannot figure out why. With GDB, I was able to confirm that this dereference caused the error:

```
(gdb) disassemble
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000100000fa2 <+0>: pushq  $0x32
=> 0x0000000100000fa4 <+2>: mov    (%esp),%eax
   0x0000000100000fa8 <+6>: mov    $0x0,%rdi
   0x0000000100000faf <+13>:    mov    $0x2000001,%rax
   0x0000000100000fb6 <+20>:    syscall
End of assembler dump.
(gdb)
```

But I cannot figure out why. Does anyone acquainted with the stack in x86 know what I am doing wrong?

How I am assembling: `gcc -masm=intel access_stack_via_pointer.asm`
It's also important to note that I am on MacOS.

```
    .global _main
    .text
_main:
    push 50

    # why the segmentation fault?
    # eax should have 50 in it
    mov eax, [esp]

    mov rdi, 0
    mov rax, 0x2000001
    syscall
```

Comment: That's a 32-bit tutorial.  If you want to port it to 64-bit mode, you have to understand the differences.  It should be obvious in GDB if you do `info reg` that RSP has a value larger than 32-bit, so RSP != ESP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Segfault when loading from \[esp\] in 64-bit code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54498071)  (also [A modification to %esp cause SIGSEGV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15656887))

Comment: bleh, the only tag you used that I have a gold badge in was [x86], you left out [assembly].  Since this is specifically an x86-64 problem, I retagged it and then couldn't dup-hammer.

Comment: Note that you really shouldn't port a tutorial to a different architecture while following it.

Comment: @PeterCordes prl solved my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 64-bit mode, the stack pointer is RSP, not ESP. Using ESP uses the low 32 bits of the register, which isn’t a valid memory address.

Comment: Duplicate of [Segfault when loading from \[esp\] in 64-bit code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54498071), if you want to help close this.