# My char pointer points to invalid value after being cast from int*

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am learning C programming language, I have just started learning **arrays with pointers**. I have problem in this question, I hope the that output must be **`5`** but it is **`2`**, Can anyone please explain why?

```
int main(){
   int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
   char *ptr = (char *) arr;
   printf("%d", *(ptr+4));
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If anyone votes down this question then please mention your comment, it is very tough for me, hopefully not for others.... :)

Comment: You have an "int" array, but a "char" pointer.

Comment: +1 on your announcement :)

Comment: By the way, you would have expected your output to be 5, not 4: `*ptr` points to the first element of the array, which is 1, four elements after it you have 5. 5 would have been the output if you had defined `int *ptr = (int *) arr;`

Comment: I would suggest changing the topic of this question to something more useful. This question may get asked in the future. I'd suggest *My char pointer points to ivalid value after being cast from int\**" or sth like that. I'd edit the question, but there's too many upvotes and I don't want to mess with such a popular qustion.

Comment: @Dariusz What about "Char pointer returns unexpected value after being cast from int*"?

Comment: @Dariusz, I am totally agree with you, but generally when people feel problems then they try to ask them, rather than thinking that how to ask them effectively...... :)

Comment: @user2320537 well I know that, and mind that I didn't rage at you or anything. But since this question has received such recognition, I think you ought to rethink the title to help other people who have the same problem.

Comment: @Dariusz, sure sir, i will remember this from next time, and thanks for this invaluable suggestion... :)

Comment: @user2320537 ... you still haven't changed the topic! You can edit the post!

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Assumed a little endian architecture where an int is 32 bits (4 bytes), the individual bytes of `int arr[]` look like this (least significant byte at the lower address. All values in hex):

```
|01 00 00 00|02 00 00 00|03 00 00 00|04 00 00 00|05 00 00 00
```

```
char *ptr = (char *) arr;
```

Now, `ptr` points to the first byte - since you have casted to `char*`, it is treated as char array onwards:

```
|1|0|0|0|2|0|0|0|3|0|0|0|4|0|0|0|5|0|0|0
 ^
 +-- ptr
```

Then, `*(ptr+4)` accesses the fifth element of the char array and returns the corresponding `char` value:

```
|1|0|0|0|2|0|0|0|3|0|0|0|4|0|0|0|5|0|0|0
         ^
         +-- *(ptr + 4) = 2
```

Hence, `printf()` prints `2`.

On a [Big Endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) system, the order of the bytes within each `int` is reversed, resulting in

```
|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|2|0|0|0|3|0|0|0|4|0|0|0|5
         ^
         +-- *(ptr + 4) = 0
```

Comment: You mix your endianess, little endian have the lowest by in the lowest memory location.

Comment: Your description of how `printf()` handles this case is incorrect. It's getting the value of the 5th character as an integer, not a pointer to same. Also, as Joachim says, your endianness is flipped.

Answer (score 13):

It's because the size of `char` is one, and the size of `int` is four. This means that adding `4` to `ptr` makes the result point to the second entry in the `int` array.

If you compiled this on a big [endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) system you would have printed 33554432 instead.

Comment: I thought that endian only applied to floating point. Are you suggesting that integers behave in the same way? I'm not so sure.

Comment: Wherever there is a type that uses more than 1 byte there is a question of what order to store the bytes in.

Comment: @Bathsheba Endianess is *definitely* an integer problem.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg; +1 then and my lunchtime reading plans changed: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: @JoachimPileborg On a big endian system, would this not also result in 2 since printf() interprets the bytes also in the other direction?

Comment: @Andreas It does interprets the _bytes_ in the reverse direction, not the _bits_ in each bytes. `0x0004` becomes `0x4000`, not `0x2000`.

Comment: @MatthieuRouget Right, what I meant is 2 in LE is `00 00 00 02`, and `02 00 00 00` in BE - but still, `02 00 00 00` would  be passed to printf(), which should again interpret it as 2 on a BE machine ...

Comment: @Andreas: Yes OK, your are right. If the array is big endian in the first place, it should also be 2 with %d. I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: @Andreas No, an `int` with value 2 is `02 00 00 00` in little endian. The lowest byte comes at the lowest address.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg +1 - I remember that I **always** mess them up :D

Comment: @Andreas I do that as well, especially since I started my career on a big-endian platform. Little-endian just feels... wrong! :)

Comment: ... and, I think that you were right in the first place: On big endian, the result should be zero, since you are accessing the fifth byte as `char` and this byte is zero... sorry for that ...

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: So will the output be 0 or 33554432 on big endian machine?

Answer (score 3):

```
int main(){
 int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
 char *ptr = (char *) arr;
 printf("%d",*(ptr+4));
 return 0;
}
```

Each case of `arr` has `sizeof(int)` size (which may be 4 on your implementation).

Since `ptr` is a pointer to `char`, [pointer arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29#C_and_C.2B.2B) makes `ptr + 4` points 4 bytes after `&arr[0]`, which may be `&arr[1]`.

In memory, it looks like something like:

```
Address | 0 1 2 3 | 4 5 6 7 | ...
Value   |  arr[0] |  arr[1] | ...
```

Answer (score 2):

On a 32 bit platform, `int` is four times the size of `char`. When you add 4 to `ptr`, you add 4 times the *size of what ptr points to* to ptr (which itself is a memory location). That happens to be the address of the second element in the `int` array.

On a 64 bit platform, `int` is **eight** times the size of `char`; and your output would be very different.

To cut a long story short, your code is not portable, (also see Joachim Pileborg's answer re endianness) but amusing to unpick.

Comment: `int` storage size is implementation dependent. On most 64 bits platforms, `sizeof(int)` is 4. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384502/what-is-the-bit-size-of-long-on-64-bit-windows for more infos.

Answer (score 2):

What you do is definitely not recommended in production code, but is definitely great for understanding pointers, casts, etc. in the learning process, so for this your example is great. So, why you get 2. It is because your array is an array of ints, which depending on your architecture has different size (in your case, `sizeof(int)` is 4). You define `ptr` as being a char pointer, char has size 1 byte. Pointer arithmetics (that's what you do when you write `ptr+4`) works with size of objects the pointer references, in your case with chars. Thus `ptr+4` is 4 bytes away from the beginning of your array, and thus at the 2nd position of your `int` array. That is it. Try `ptr+5`, you should get 0.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are coverting int* to char*, ptr[0] = 1, ptr[4] = 2, ptr[8] = 3, ptr[12] = 4 , ptr[16] = 5 and all others equal to 0. ptr+4 points to 4th element in the ptr array. So result is 2.

Comment: that depends on the endianness of your system. You didn't explain why it works like that and why it's correct on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(){
 int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
 char *ptr = (char *) arr;
 printf("%d",*(ptr+4));
 return 0;
}
```

Imagine `arr` is stored at the address `100` (totally dumb address). So you have:
`arr[0]` is stored at the address 100.
`arr[1]` is stored at the address 104. (there's is +4 because of the type `int`)
`arr[2]` is stored at the address 108.
`arr[3]` is stored at the address 112. Etc etc.

Now you're doing `char *ptr = (char *) arr;`, so `ptr` = 100 (the same as `arr`).
The next statement is interesting, specially the second argument of `printf` : `*(ptr+4)`.
Keep in my mind that `ptr` = 100. So `ptr + 4` = 104, the same address that `arr[1]` ! So it will print the value of `arr[1]`, which is 2.