# Why are python's for loops so non-linear for large inputs?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, benchmarking

I was benchmarking some python code I noticed something strange. I used the following function to measure how fast it took to iterate through an empty for loop:

```
def f(n):
    t1 = time.time()
    for i in range(n):
        pass
    print(time.time() - t1)
```

`f(10**6)` prints about `0.035`, `f(10**7)` about `0.35`, `f(10**8)` about `3.5`, and `f(10**9)` about `35`. But `f(10**10)`? Well over `2000`. That's certainly unexpected. Why would it take over 60 times as long to iterate through 10 times as many elements? What's with python's for loops that causes this? Is this python-specific, or does this occur in a lot of languages?

Comment: you are creating a list if you are using python2, your timing  would also be better using the timeit module

Comment: from `10**6` to `10**9` there is a huge difference. _Exponential growth_

Comment: Then I think it's caused by the fact that 10^9 fits in a standard 32-bits integer while for 10^10 python uses arbitrary size integers. This makes every comparison slower.

Comment: Maybe python allocates memory for the list. For too many items, The OS is paging out to disk space.

Comment: @clemos24 Not in Py3, `range` returns a generator, not a list.

Comment: @user3002473, what exact version of python are you using because I have timed the code and get nothing even remotely close to the difference in your timings?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Python 3.4.1.

Comment: As you can see I ran the tests using the timeit module on my own notebook and they are quite a bit different to yours. I also used python3.4. It would be interesting to try and run the tests using timeit on your machine.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you get above `10^9` you get out of 32bit integer range. Python3 then transparently moves you onto [arbitrary precision integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic), which are much slower to allocate and use.

In general working with such big numbers is one of the areas where Python3 is a lot slower that Python2 (which at least had fast 64bit integers on many systems). On the good side it makes python easier to use, with fewer [overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) type errors.

Comment: It started with Pep237: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/ which made longs arbitrary precision. Later Python3 got rid of the int type which slowed things down. During the 3.x releases I believe they have been working to introduce more optimizations for smaller integers.

Comment: The actual difference in run time seems to be completely platform specific .

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I've been trying to read the source code for the long implementation, to see exactly what optimisations are made when. There is certainly the choice of whether a digit should be 15 or 30 bits, but after that it became a lot of work deciphering it all.

Answer (score 5):

Some accurate timings using `timeit` show the times actually roughly increase in line with the input size so your timings seem to be quite a ways off:

```
In [2]: for n in [10**6,10**7,10**8,10**9,10**10]:
               % timeit f(n)
   ...:     
10 loops, best of 3: 22.8 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 226 ms per loop # roughly ten times previous
1 loops, best of 3: 2.26 s per loop # roughly ten times previous
1 loops, best of 3: 23.3 s per loop # roughly ten times previous
1 loops, best of 3: 4min 18s per loop # roughly ten times previous
```

Using xrange and python2 we see the ratio roughly the same, obviously python2 is much faster overall due to the fact python3 int has been replaced by long:

```
In [5]: for n in [10**6,10**7,10**8,10**9,10**10]:
               % timeit f(n)
   ...:     
100 loops, best of 3: 11.3 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 113 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 1.13 s per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 11.4 s per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 1min 56s per loop
```

The actual difference in run time seems to be  more related to the size of  [window's long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384502/what-is-the-bit-size-of-long-on-64-bit-windows) rather than directly related to python 3. The difference is marginal when using unix which handles longs much differently to windows so this is a platform specific issue as much if not more than a python one.

Comment: I just ran another test, and I got the following results:

`10**6` - 0.07520970538367432 seconds, 
`10**7` - 0.36399144430744984 seconds,
`10**8` - 3.492611703306957 seconds,
`10**9` - 34.71252936832384 seconds,
`10**10` - 2190.0514266665177 seconds.

Could it be a difference in what system we're running it on?

Comment: @user3002473. What are you running it on?

Comment: @PadriacCunningham Windows 7 64-bit, Intel  Core i5 3.20 GHz processor with 4.00 GB of RAM installed.

Comment: @user3002473. I am on Ubuntu 14.04 with similar specs. I cannot think of any obvious reason  it is running so slow. Have you tried it using  python 2 with xrange ?

Comment: @PadriacCunningham I just tried running the same test in python 2.7.2 with `xrange`, and it's giving me an `OverflowError` for `xrange(10**10)`, but up until then the times were `0.0447` seconds, `0.168` seconds, `1.65` seconds, and `15.6` seconds.

Comment: @user3002473,  you are bound by the size of the windows long, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384502/what-is-the-bit-size-of-long-on-64-bit-windows so that is why you get the `OverflowError`.  It may be a factor as to why you get such poor performance in comparison to mu linux machine. I will do a bit more digging around tomorrow as the whole integer size explanation does not explain the whole story. If it were python specific I should have a similar performance hit