# Python 2.7.8 (64bit) on Windows (64bit) is half as fast as 2.7.8 (64bit) on Ubuntu (64bit)

Tags: python, windows, benchmarking

On Linux it takes 1.09171080828 secs.

On Windows it takes 2.14042000294 secs.

Code for the benchmark:

```
import time


def mk_array(num):
        return  [x for x in xrange(1,num)]

def run():
        arr = mk_array(10000000)
        x = 0
        start = time.time()
        x = reduce(lambda x,y: x + y, arr)
        done = time.time()
        elapsed = done - start
        return elapsed

if __name__ == '__main__':
        times = [run() for x in xrange(0,100)]
        avg = sum(times)/len(times)
        print (avg)
```

I am aware that the GIL creates more or less single threaded scripts.

Windows box is my Hyper-V host but should be beefy enough to run a single threaded script at full bore. 12-cores 2.93Ghz Intel X5670s, 72GB ram, etc.

Ubuntu VM has 4-cores and 8GB of ram.

Both are running Python 2.7.8 64-bit.

Why is windows half as fast?

edit: I've lopped two zeros and linux finishes in 0.010593495369 seconds, and windows in 0.171899962425 seconds. Thanks everyone, curiosity satisfied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of the size of the [long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384502/what-is-the-bit-size-of-long-on-64-bit-windows) in windows, in windows a `long` is `32` bits in unix it is `64` bits so you are hitting [Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) issues sooner which are costlier to allocate.

Related question [Why are python's for loops so non-linear for large inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28662188/why-are-pythons-for-loops-so-non-linear-for-large-inputs/28662466#28662466)

If you benchmark the xrange alone you will see a considerable difference.

The reasoning behind windows use of LLP64 seems to be compatibility with 32-bit code:

> Another alternative is the LLP64 model, which maintains compatibility with 32-bit code by leaving both int and long as 32-bit. "LL" refers to the "long long integer" type, which is at least 64 bits on all platforms, including 32-bit environments.

Taken from [wiki/64-bit_computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing)

Comment: So the problem is that the 64-bit Windows version of Python uses `long` rather than `longlong` ?  Any idea why?

Comment: @HarryJohnston, see [Include/intobject.h](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ee879c0ffa11/Include/intobject.h#l23) for the definition of a `PyIntObject`. When the value exceeds the maximum value of a C `long`, the interpreter switches to using an arbitrary precision `PyLongObject`. Python 3 does away with `PyIntObject` and only uses arbitrary-precision integers.

Comment: I understand why Visual C++ defines a long to be 32-bits for both 32-bit and 64-bit code.  What I don't understand is why the 64-bit version of Python uses long rather than longlong on the Windows platform, and that doesn't seem to be addressed in any of those links.  It's not a big deal, though, I was just curious.  It may be as simple as "because all the code already uses long and we don't want to change it all". :-)  (I'd have thought `#define long longlong` would take care of it in one hit, but I guess that might have unwelcome side-effects.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston, that would have required rewriting a lot of code to use a conditionally defined `PY_LONG` macro. I don't think anyone bothered with such a major rewrite because core devs don't like working on Python 2. Most of the effort goes into Python 3 development, which no longer uses `PyIntObject`.

Comment: @eryksun: that sounds reasonable.  Thanks.