# ICMP packet sniffing not receiving any data (Black Hat Python Book)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, packet-sniffers, icmp

I came across this code snippet from the book, **Black hat Python**, Chapter 3. The Network: Raw Sockets and Sniffing :

```
import socket
import os

host = "x.x.x.x"        # Host to listen on

# Create a raw socket and bind it to the public interface
if os.name == "nt":
    socket_protocol = socket.IPPROTO_IP
else:
    socket_protocol = socket.IPPROTO_ICMP
    
sniffer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket_protocol)
sniffer.bind((host, 0))
sniffer.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)     # We want the IP headers included in the capture
# if we're using Windows, we need to send an IOCTL
# to set up promiscuous mode
if os.name == "nt":
    sniffer.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)
print(sniffer.recvfrom(65565))      # Read in a single packet

# If we're using Windows, turn off promiscuous mode
if os.name == "nt":
    sniffer.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_OFF)
```

And when I do `ping google.com` the above code is supposed to capture the first ping packet, but instead **waits for the packet indefinitely** in the line `print(sniffer.recvfrom(65565))`.

I tried with `host` as my machine's local ip and with localhost, and tried changing the buffer size as seen in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306747/python-sniffing-from-black-hat-python-book). But it did not good.

I works when I set `host = ""` and do `ping 127.0.0.1`, but not when I ping other urls.

Can somebody please tell me what is wrong?

I am using Python 3.8.2 and Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: when you ping other IP/url then it sends request directly to other IP/ulr and there is no reason to send to your local IP.

Comment: as I know tools to capture packets need library [pcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap) (`packet capture`). I have to also run code as `root` (using `sudo`) on Linux Mint (based on Ubuntu 18.04). I used `0.0.0.0` to listening on all my network cards (`LAN`, `WiFi`) and I got some result.

Comment: @furas Thank you for the comment, I got the solution because of the you told you got it working. And I analyzed why it was working in some cases, which led me to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not actually with the code, it is a compatibility issue, pinging the more modern servers are done by `IPv6`, while the code picks only `IPv4` ICMP packets. An easy solution will be to restrict the ping to `IPv4` by :

```
ping -4 google.com
```

The sniffer for `IPv6` only requires small changes form the `IPv4` version, it is as follows :

```
import socket
import os

host = ""       # Host to listen on

# Create a raw socket and bind it to the public interface
if os.name == "nt":
    socket_protocol = socket.IPPROTO_IPV6
else:
    socket_protocol = socket.IPPROTO_ICMPV6
    
sniffer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket_protocol)
sniffer.bind((host, 0))
sniffer.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)       # We want the IP headers included in the capture
# if we're using Windows, we need to send an IOCTL
# to set up promiscuous mode
if os.name == "nt":
    sniffer.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)
print(sniffer.recvfrom(65565))      # Read in a single packet

# If we're using Windows, turn off promiscuous mode
if os.name == "nt":
    sniffer.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_OFF)
```