# Python - large numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7, largenumber

Is there anyway to run a for loop with a range of over 13 characters?
For example:

```
for i in range (1000000000000):
```

I know this won't work but is there any way it could?

Comment: `range()` works fine in Python3 (returns an iterator), however `range()` returns a list in Python2, use `xrange()` for an iterator. You can iterate for as long as you want with no additional memory overhead.

Comment: When I use xrange it says 'Python int too large to convert to C long'

Comment: Can't replicate, which python are you using?

Comment: @AChampion python 2.7

Comment: I presume you are using windows?

Comment: I am using windows 10. What do you mean by platform?

Comment: @T.Green, he means OS, a long is 32bits on windows so even using xrange you won't be able to store a number that  large

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `xrange` can also give you `Python int too large to convert to C long` Error as the number has to fit into a C long. To overcome this use [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) to create you own range:

```
  from itertools import count

def myx_range(start, end):
    return iter(count(start).next, end)
```

If you wanted to use the same logic with python 3:

```
from itertools import count

def myx_range(start, end):
    cn = count(start)
    return iter(lambda: next(cn), end)
```

Or a `while` loop:

```
from itertools import count

def myx_range(start, end):
    while start < end:
        yield start
        start += 1
```

A long is `32bit` on windows so you are going to hit the limit using `xrange` with  a number that large.

See [what-is-the-bit-size-of-long-on-64-bit-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384502/what-is-the-bit-size-of-long-on-64-bit-windows)

Comment: Good sentinel use of `iter()`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in my program. I have to do a nested loop with the same parameters on each loop and it won't work on the second loop.

Comment: @T.Green, how would it not?  `for i in myx_range(0, 100000000000)` will work as many times as you want it to

Comment: How exactly are you using it?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I was using it wrong, I thought the function was the loop, I didn't realise ro had to write the `for i in myx_range(0, 1000000000000)` but know it works. Thanks! :)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: FYI, the first version could simplify to `return iter(count(start).next, end)` and halve the runtime overhead (it moves all the work per iteration to the C layer). Sure, it's not portable to Py3 (where iteration is done with `__next__` instead of `next`), but if you need to work on both Py2 and Py3, I'd suggest doing a version check and only using homegrown code for `myx_range` on Py2, on Py3, you'd just make `myx_range` an alias of `range`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, True, originally I did not have it in a function  so just left the loop. I changed it but kept the lambda  in case someone wanted to use a variation of it with python3.

Answer (score 3):

For python 2.7, use [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) (which uses a generator instead of initializing a large list) instead:

```
for i in xrange(1000000000000):
```

Answer (score 0):

If the bounds and step are within the range [-sys.maxsize-1, sys.maxsize), and the total number of elements is `<= sys.maxsize`, then [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) has you covered.

If not, `itertools` provides the parts you need to completely reimplement `xrange` (and efficiently too, pushing all the work to the C layer in CPython) for the purposes of generation (`xrange` is a real object can be generated over and over and supports a few other features; this only generates, and only once per call):

```
from itertools import count, islice

def myxrange(stop, *args):
    '''Replacement for xrange to generate ranges of arbitrarily large numbers efficiently
    '''
    start, step = 0, 1  # Defaults when only one argument passed
    if args:
        if len(args) > 2:
            raise TypeError("myxrange expected at most 3 arguments, got {}".format(len(args)))
        start = stop  # When 2+ args passed, stop is really start
        stop, step = (args + (1,))[:2]  # Use step if given, otherwise 1
    # islice slices x items, we need to calculate the number to slice
    # from the bounds given
    numitems = (stop - start + (step - (1 if step > 0 else -1))) // step
    return islice(count(start, step), numitems)
```

The above is obviously slightly overkill to handle `step`s other than the default 1; it could be simplified dramatically if `step` support wasn't needed.

In CPython (the reference interpreter) this should run more efficiently than using Python level code (which requires repeated byte code execution); once initialized, `islice` and `count` do all their work at the C layer, which can dramatically improve performance. For example, compared to the `while` based loop from the other answer, in ipython running on Python 2.7 on my machine:

```
>>> %timeit -r5 list(xrange(10, 2000))
100000 loops, best of 5: 15.2 μs per loop
>>> %timeit -r5 list(myxrange(10, 2000)) # Version in my answer
10000 loops, best of 5: 24.9 μs per loop
>>> %timeit -r5 list(myxrange2(10, 2000)) # Version using while from Padraig's answer
1000 loops, best of 5: 173 μs per loop

# Padraig's count based version takes 124 μs, though it could be optimized
# down to ~59 μs by changing it to the C layer version (though either
# version breaks if start > stop):
def myxrange(start, stop):
    return iter(count(start).next, end)
```

Even with the overhead of mimicking `xrange`s non-standard argument prototype, the overhead for the `count`+`islice` code is only about 50% over `xrange`, which ain't half bad given that it actually handles scenarios `xrange` can't.

Answer (score -2):

Remember that there is a limit of minumum and maximum value to store in processor register. It means that not all modules can receive big numbers as arguments.