# Sum of consecutive integers in numpy is incorrect

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sum

In summing the first `100,000,000` positive integers using the following:

```
import numpy as np
np.arange(1,100000001).sum()
```

I return: `987459712`, which does not match the formula: `N(N+1)/2` for `N=100000000`. Namely, the formula returns `5000000050000000`.

Before posting, I wrote the following, which returns `True`:

```
np.arange(1,65536).sum() == ((65535+1) * 65535)/2
```

However, the number `65536` seems to be a critical point, as

```
np.arange(1,65537).sum() == ((65536+1) * 65536)/2
```

returns `False`.

For integers greater than `65536` the code returns `False`, whereas integers below this threshold return `True`.

Could someone explain either what I've done wrong in calculating the sum, or what is going on with the code?

Comment: This feels like an implementation-specific behavior. What version and implementation of Python are you on? I could correctly compute the expected result using CPython 3.6.3 on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: I'd guess numpy assumes ints given the numbers. But usually int can hold up to 65536. After that you have an overflow and you get inconsistencies.

Comment: And to also clarify, I'm on numpy version 1.12.1

Comment: I'm also using numpy version 1.12.1. The python version is 3.6.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like `numpy` sometimes has a hard time guessing the correct datatype.

On my system, Win 10 64-bit, Python 3.4.4, numpy 1.13.1:

```
>>  np.arange(1, 100000001).sum()
987459712
>>  np.arange(1, 100000001).dtype
dtype('int32')
```

But, if we "help" `numpy` it gets the correct result:

```
>> np.arange(1, 100000001, dtype=np.int64).sum()
500000005000000
```

The wrong result is obviously due to 32-bit integer overflowing.

Comment: That `500000005000000` looks strange there. Weirdly I get the same but if I try other numbers different than `100000001` I get good results. Anyhow, in this case I'd use `uint64` instead of `int64`

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel could you explain the preference of uint64?

Comment: Since you're not using negative part using an unsigned type would give you more headroom and "safety" against overflowing the allocated space.

Answer (score 5):

It isn't really that `numpy` has a hard time guessing things, it's just that [the default int](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html) type is the same as C long type:

> `int_`: Default integer type (same as C long; normally either int64 or int32)

For windows systems, longs are 32bit, even on 64bit builds (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384502/what-is-the-bit-size-of-long-on-64-bit-windows) for more) so that's what's used by default, `int32`.

As DeepSpace suggested, setting `dtype` to `int64` does the trick. This can be done either in `arange` or in the `sum` method.

---

Additionally, you wrote:

> Before posting, I wrote the following, which returns `True`:
>
> `np.arange(1,65536).sum() == ((65535+1) * 65535)/2`
>
> However, the number 65536 seems to be a critical point, as
>
> `np.arange(1,65537).sum() == ((65536+1) * 65536)/2`
>
> returns `False`.

and this is explained by the fact that the second sum exceeds `int32`'s max value while the first doesn't:

```
>> np.arange(1,65536).sum() < np.iinfo(np.int32).max
True    
>>> np.arange(1,65537).sum() < np.iinfo(np.int32).max
False
```

of course the Python calculation is correct due to Python 3's arbitrary precision `int`s.

---

This is why many of us weren't able to reproduce. On most Unixes the default int size for 64bit machines is `int64` (since the `C` long is 64bits) therefore the sum of those ints was equal to the expected value.

Comment: So why does `np.arange(1, 100000001, dtype=np.int32).sum()` give the correct 64-bit result? (At least, it does on my machine: macOS, Python 3.6, NumPy 1.13.3)

Comment: @MarkDickinson the [`sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html#numpy.sum) method uses the default int size which on [most unix-like systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) is `int64`. Apparently, windows with `cygwin` should also use `int64` according to the model linked.