# NativeLongByReference contains only 32-bit number on x64 OS

Tags: java, jna

I have a strage issue with the function with reference to `typedef unsigned __int64 EntityNumber;` input parameter.

Library is x64, OS is Windows 10.

If I pass **NativeLongByReference**, the output buffer has only 4 bytes, so my number is broken if it exceeds 32-bit. I checked it with **dump** and it indeed contains half of 64-bit **Long**

If I pass **DoubleByReference** I can get my Long with `doubleByReference.pointer.getLong(0)`.

While this hack works, I wonder, what's problem with **Long** if both OSes are 64-bit?

```
long TRANS2QUIK_API __stdcall TRANS2QUIK_SEND_SYNC_TRANSACTION (LPSTR lpstTransactionString, long* pnReplyCode, PDWORD pdwTransId, EntityNumber* pnOrderNum, LPSTR lpstrResultMessage, DWORD dwResultMessageSize, long* pnExtendedErrorCode, LPSTR lpstErrorMessage, DWORD dwErrorMessageSize);
```

and JNA interface

```
    NativeLong TRANS2QUIK_SEND_SYNC_TRANSACTION(
            String lpstTransactionString,
            NativeLongByReference pnReplyCode,
            NativeLongByReference pdwTransId,
            DoubleByReference pdOrderNum, <- hack!
            byte[] lpstrResultMessage,
            int dwResultMessageSize,
            NativeLongByReference pnExtendedErrorCode,
            byte[] lpstrErrorMessage,
            int dwErrorMessageSize
    );
```

```
openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.4+11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, [a `long` is a 32-bit integer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=vs-2019), regardless of the OS bitness.

Therefore `NativeLong` will point to a 32-bit `long` value on Windows, and is not necessary to use in Windows code.  The `NativeLong` type is more applicable to *nix operating systems.

You can see this in the JNA source, where the size of a `NativeLong` is defined in [Native.java](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/src/com/sun/jna/Native.java) where `LONG_SIZE` derives from the native `sizeof()` function for the `long` type, [a 32-bit integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384502/what-is-the-bit-size-of-long-on-64-bit-windows).

The type that does change size on Windows is the `Pointer` type.  In fact, the pointer to the `NativeLongByReference` is 32/64 bit on the respective systems, while the value pointed to is 32 bits.

In your case, your variable is clearly defined as a 64-bit integer, so `LongByReference` would be the correct mapping.

Comment: It might be worth noting, that for a value, that is 64bit on all platforms, `LongByReference` is the right choice.