# Pandas Dataframe: Why is astype method producing int32 results with an argument of int

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Python 3.8 and Pandas 1.3.  Here is some sample code:

```
    data_dc = {'Dates': ['10212021','11152021','01142022','02122022']}
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_dc)
    print(df1['Dates'].astype(int))
```

Results:

```
0    10212021
1    11152021
2     1142022
3     2122022
Name: Dates, dtype: int32
```

I specified a Python data type (int) as the argument of the astype method and expected a dtype of the Dates column to be int64.  Instead, I got int32.  Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?  This is easy to work around, but I like to make sure I understand what to expect from the software.

Comment: I get int64, so maybe it is something with your config?!! idk

Comment: AFAIK `dtype(int)` is the default integer type of `numpy`. This is determined by the size of the `long int` type of your system's c compiler. This is usually 32-bit on [windows 64-bit OS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/384502/14277722).

Comment: OK.  The documentation says you have to put numpy types in quotes but not the python types which arr float, int and str.  Every example I see online that uses int gets a dtype of int64.

Comment: I just tried the same code on Linux Mint running on Virtual Box and got the int64 result.  Running on Windows 11, I get int32.  Can it be a Windows issue?

Comment: My Windows OS is 64 bit and I have confirmed that my Python is 64 bit as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas uses numpy datatypes under the hood. From the numpy documentation,

> The default NumPy behavior is to create arrays in either 32 or 64-bit
> signed integers (platform dependent and matches C int size) or double
> precision floating point numbers, int32/int64 and float, respectively.
> If you expect your integer arrays to be a specific type, then you need
> to specify the dtype while you create the array.

It is not a bug and you should be specifying dtypes if you have a specific use or want to be platform agnostic. To rephrase your question, what is `np.dtype(int)` on my platform?

On windows, as some of the comments suggest, it appears to be a C `signed long` (32 bits). You can even get numpy to throw an overflow error to confirm this.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array([2_147_483_648], dtype=int) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Comment: OK.  I tried that code and got the result you showed.  I was under the impression that, if you specifies Python int, you would always get int64.  Thanks  for your detailed answer.  That was a big help in understanding more about Python.