# 32 bit builtin population count for clang counts long long integer c++

Tags: c++, built-in, bitcount

I was using the `__builtin_popcount` with clang compiler and I needed to count a 64 bit number (`unsigned long long` or `uint64_t`). From looking it up, `__builtin_popcount` counts 16 bits, `__builtin_popcountl` counts 32 bits, and `__builtin_popcountll` counts 64 bits. When I tested it, `__builtin_popcountl` was able to do calculations on 64 bit integers. Does anybody know the reason for this?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned long long bb = 0b1000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001;
    std::cout << __builtin_popcountl(bb) << std::endl; //returns 9 (correct answer)
}
```

Comment: Looking it up where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`int __builtin_popcountl (unsigned long)`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005fpopcountl) is for `unsigned long`s.
[`int __builtin_popcountll (unsigned long long)`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005fpopcountll) is for `unsigned long long`s.

`unsigned long` is 64 bit on your platform, so the conversion from `unsigned long long` to `unsigned long` is lossless, and you can use `__builtin_popcountl` for 64 bit numbers too.

`int` is guaranteed to be 16 bits or wider, `long` is guaranteed to be 32 bits or wider, and `long long` is guaranteed to be 64 bits or wider. That means you can always use `__builtin_popcountl` with 32 bit numbers, and you may or may not be able to use it with 64 bit numbers (in this case you could).

Related question: [What is the bit size of long on 64-bit Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/384502)